# Vararg x86-64 ABI. Number of floating point parameters in registers

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, abi

I'm looking at [`x86-64` ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) and have a question about the example in `Figure 3.31` and `Figure 3.32`:

```
int a, b;
long double ld;
double m, n;
__m256 u, y;
__m512 v, z;
extern void func (int a, double m, __m256 u, __m512 v, ...);
func (a, m, u, v, b, ld, y, z, n);
```

It was said that when passing arguments to the `func` function `%rax` contained 3, but I could see only 2 floating point values passed in registers: `ld` and `m`. So I implemented the following example:

`impl.c`:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

unsigned long func(int a, double m, __m256 u, __m512 v, ...){
    unsigned long rax;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "" :
        "=a" (rax) : :
    );
    return rax;
}
```

`main.c`

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long func(int a, double m, __m256 u, __m512 v, ...);

int main(void){
    int a = 10,
        b = 20;
    long double ld = 30.0;
    double m = 40.0,
           n = 50.0;
    __m256 u, y;
    __m512 v, z;
    printf("%lu\n", func(a, m, u, v, b, ld, y, z, n)); //prints 2
}
```

Is it a typo? So the correct content of register `%rax` should be `2` instead of `3`?

Comment: Why don't you just use a debugger like a normal person instead of hoping that GCC doesn't clobber the incoming RAX with your inline-asm hack?  Or write the function in pure asm.

Comment: @RaymondChen `n` is supposed to be on the stack.

Comment: It's the 7th FP arg, it's in XMM7.  Unlike Windows x64, integer args don't steal register slots from FP args and vice versa.

Comment: @PeterCordes Can it clobber the incoming RAX? If it does would not it break the ABI?

Comment: I think the figure 3.32 is totally b0rked. There is no mention of `z` for example, and it says that "Only named __m256 and __m512 arguments may be passed
in register" and it then shows a vararg __m256 being passed in a register...

Comment: Yes, sure it can.  It can generate any code it wants to between checking incoming AL and the code for your inline asm statement.  e.g. with optimization disabled, it will set up a stack frame and spill the fixed args to the stack.  It probably doesn't modify RAX but it's not in general a safe assumption.  Setting a breakpoint with a debugger would be vastly easier, and so would `asm("func: ret");` at global scope.

Comment: Ok, I found a better one: https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf - different 3.32

Comment: Strange that the paper I found *predates* in versions, maybe they somehow messed up the revisions :P

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It seems they introduced the bug in newer version when trying to add an example with `__m512`. Anyway, should `rax` really contain `3`?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: that older version of the ABI predates `__m512`.  The version linked in the question is the (still current I think) 1.0 version.  If they introduced bogus wording, check https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/tree/hjl/master for the change in the LaTeX source; there's also a discussion forum for the ABI; there's probably a message somewhere about the reason for the change.

Comment: @PeterCordes hmm https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/blame/hjl/master/low-level-sys-info.tex#L661 the blame is not helpful at all...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I don't see a variadic `__m256` passed in regs.  ymm1 and zmm2 are fixed args and `y` is on the stack.  I do see that they failed to update 3.32 to include `z` on the stack, though, at 64.  Since `al` is supposed to be the *total* number of args in vector regs (including the fixed args), the correct value is `4` in the updated ABI (with a `__m512` fixed args), and `3` in the older ABI.

Comment: oops sorry, wrong link above, should have been https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/blame/hjl/master/low-level-sys-info.tex#L2076 line 2076

Comment: @PeterCordes Why does GCC use the value `2` for the older ABI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ABI doc has an error: it should be `al=4` for that example.  This figure only got partially updated when adding AVX512 `__m512`; it was previously correct with `al=3`, e.g. [in the 0.99.7 revision of the ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) without the fixed `__m512` arg.

@AnttiHaapala is correct that they also failed to update 3.32 to show `z` on the stack, at `64:`.

`al` is supposed to be the *total* number of args in vector regs (including the fixed args).  **This includes *any* arg in XMM registers, whether it's scalar or `__m128` (which *can* be passed as variadic).**  Or for fixed args, also including `__m256` and `__m512`.  (Wide vectors are passed on the stack for variadic functions; variadic functions that (might) use `va_arg` on a `__m256` don't need dump all the YMM regs, still only XMM.  There is very little use-case for passing variadic SIMD vectors.)

But note that 80-bit `long double ld` is *not* passed in an XMM register.  SSE/AVX instructions can't do anything with 80-bit x87 extended precision data so forcing functions to copy it to/from an XMM reg and then back into an x87 stack reg makes no sense.

---

Note that the upper bytes of RAX must be ignored by the callee.  It's often convenient for the caller to `mov eax, 3` instead of just `mov al,3` to avoid the possibility of false dependencies; the ABI doc's diagram is based on GCC's normal behaviour and should actually say `%al`, not `%rax`

---

> Why does GCC use the value 2 for older ABI?

**Because you forgot to actually enable AVX (and AVX512) when compiling.**

The ABI doc assumes that `__m256` variables will only be used on machines with YMM registers (AVX support) so they can be passed in registers.

If you get this wrong, GCC warns you about it:

```
<source>: In function 'void caller()':
<source>:11:9: warning: AVX vector argument without AVX enabled changes the ABI [-Wpsabi]
   11 |    func (a, m, u, v, b, ld, y, z, n);
      |    ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

<source>:11:9: note: the ABI for passing parameters with 32-byte alignment has changed in GCC 4.6
<source>:11:9: warning: AVX512F vector argument without AVX512F enabled changes the ABI [-Wpsabi]
```

Compiling with `gcc -O3` gives that warning and includes `mov eax,2` in the asm for a `caller()` containing the `func()` call from the ABI doc.

Compiling with `gcc -O3 -march=skylake-avx512` (or `-mavx512f`) gives `4`.  Or `3` if you were to leave out one of the args that go into a vector register.

It's usually a safe bet that GCC correctly implements the ABI so you can just look at its code to see what happens.  Constructing a convoluted way to actually *print* RAX is way more complicated, and stopped you from noticing that your code wasn't using AVX512.

```
void caller() {
   func (a, m, u, v, b, ld, y, z, n);
}
```

compiles properly to this asm (**[Godbolt, gcc9.2 `-O3 -march=skylake-avx512`](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0Aint+a,+b%3B%0Along+double+ld%3B%0Adouble+m,+n%3B%0A__m256+u,+y%3B%0A__m512+v,+z%3B%0Aextern+void+func+(int+a,+double+m,+__m256+u,+__m512+v,+...)%3B%0A%0Avoid+caller()+%7B%0A+++func+(a,+m,+u,+v,+b,+ld,+y,+z,+n)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:42.952380952380956,l:'4',m:48.25699116408237,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dskylake-avx512',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:51.74300883591763,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:42.952380952380956,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50.59396531242576,l:'4',m:63.822629969418955,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:36.177370030581045,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:57.047619047619044,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**):

```
caller():
        lea     r10, [rsp+8]
        and     rsp, -64                # align the stack by 64
        push    QWORD PTR [r10-8]
        mov     eax, 4                  # AL = 4 args in vector regs
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp                # frame pointer for some reason?
        push    r10
        sub     rsp, 152                # reserve space for args
        vmovaps zmm4, ZMMWORD PTR z[rip]
        vmovaps ymm5, YMMWORD PTR y[rip]
        vmovaps ZMMWORD PTR [rsp+48], zmm4
        vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rsp+16], ymm5  # copy the variadic wide vectors to their slots
        push    QWORD PTR ld[rip+8]
        vmovsd  xmm3, QWORD PTR n[rip]      # n passed in xmm3
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR b[rip]       # b passed in ESI
        push    QWORD PTR ld[rip]           # low half of 16-byte  ld
        vmovaps zmm2, ZMMWORD PTR v[rip]
        vmovaps ymm1, YMMWORD PTR u[rip]    # fixed args passed in x/y/zmm0..2
        vmovsd  xmm0, QWORD PTR m[rip]
        mov     edi, DWORD PTR a[rip]       # a passed in EDI

        call    func(int, double, float __vector(8), float __vector(16), ...)

        mov     r10, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        sub     rsp, -128
        leave
        lea     rsp, [r10-8]                 # stack-alignment cleanup
        ret
```

4 args in vector regs, AL = 4.